# Isotopope - number images and height

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope

I have a problem with my code, i word at a new website where i want make the thing more attractive. My code is:

```
<div class="portfolioFilter">


      <ul class="portfolio-isotope-filter clearfix">
            <li class="selected"><a href="#" data-filter="*"><span>All</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".people"><span>Concerte</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".places"><span>Spectacole</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-filter=".food"><span>Prezentari</span></a></li>
        </ul>

</div>


<div id="imagini-artists">
   <div class="portfolioContainer cf">

    <div class="objects">
        <img src="img/artists/1.png" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="people places">
        <img src="img/artists/2.png" alt="image">
    </div>  

    <div class="food">
        <img src="img/artists/3.png" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="people places">
        <img src="img/artists/4.png" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="places objects">
        <img src="img/artists/5.png" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="people food objects">
        <img src="img/artists/6.png" alt="image">
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).load(function(){
  var $container = $('.portfolioContainer');
  $container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
        duration: 750,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    }
});

$('.portfolioFilter a').click(function(){
    $('.portfolioFilter .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
  }); 
 });
   </script>
```

The problem is: i can`t find where i can set the Height of 'portfolioContainer' in the chrome show me a value but is from html tag style=".." . And the second problem is with the number of images, i want to put 3 images, so maybe need to change the width for that.

http://jsfiddle.net/wC4tw/

I want some help,
Thanking you in advance

Comment: The height of `portfolioContainer` will be set dynamically by isotope dependent on the number and position of the elements within it. That is why you see an inline height value when you inspect in Chrome dev tools. If you really wish to override this height use `. portfolioContainer { height: 1000px !important; }` where `1000px` is the height you want

Comment: I added that, but, when is active 'All' - '*' the number of the images in the row is 2, i want 3.. if i change to other category, is 3.